# Joda DateTimeFormat says invalid format

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a date String and a date pattern that I would like to parse into a LocalDateTime. My code is failing when it attempts to parse the Julian day.

I am building a custom file parser, so I need to create the date String programmatically.
If I create a String literal, `final String parseDate = "1421521";`, it works correctly, but if I create a String and pass that into `formatter.parseLocalDateTime(dateResult)`, I get an `IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1421522" is malformed at "21522"`.

In summary,

```
String testDate = "1421522";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(testDate);
```

works, and

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(dateResult);
```

fails.

My datePattern is `yyDDDHH`.

Comment: It sounds like your `dateResult` doesn't contain what you think it does. My guess is whitespace.

Comment: I added a couple of prints:
`dateResult:1421522.`
`datePattern:yyDDDHH.`

Comment: `dateResult` is likely to contain non-printable characters. You can try `testDate = "14\u200e21522"` in your first example to reproduce the same error. You can do `dateResult.replaceAll("\\p{C}", "")` to remove control characters.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following,

```
String dateResult = "14" + "215" + "22";
String datePattern = "yyDDDHH";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(datePattern);
LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parseLocalDateTime(dateResult);
System.out.println(dt);
```

Output is

```
2014-08-03T22:00:00.000
```

If your problem is still not resolved, please post code that replicates the problem.

Comment: I was using a character array initially for the year. Since it was initialized to a capacity of 4, String was inserting a termination character. Thanks for your comments, they helped me narrow down the problem.